# Create a private channel using GraphAPI

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

In the Ignite 2019, Microsoft announced Teams private channel and mentioned developers could use GraphAPI to create them. I cannot find any information of how to create private channel. [Here is the GraphAPI I am looking at for creating channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available in beta version of Graph API. Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Take a look at Example #2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-2-create-private-channel-on-behalf-of-user

In short, pass `"membershipType": "private"`in your request body